# Create smart recursive function for multidimensional array which returns all arrays inside in one array

Tags: php, arrays

The main thing is multidimensional arrays can be random and I don't know exactly how many arrays inside in it. That why function should include recursion and checks does it have more array inside, example below  can't do it without pre configuration. Appreciating any help

```
$arrays = array(
    array(
        'House' => 'Baratheon',
        'Sigil' => 'A crowned stag',
        'Motto' => 'Ours is the Fury',
        ),
    array(
        'Leader' => 'Eddard Stark',
        'House' => 'Stark',
        'Motto' => 'Winter is Coming',
        'Sigil' => 'A grey direwolf'
        ),
    array(
        array('SomeArray' => 'You are cool'),
        'House' => 'Lannister',
        'Leader' => 'Tywin Lannister',
        'Sigil' => 'A golden lion'
        ),
    array(
          'Q' => 'Z'
    )
);
function next_element($array) {
    foreach ($array as $some_type) {
        if (is_array($some_type)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
               }
    }
}


function check_in($inputs) {
    foreach ($inputs as $position => $input) {
    
        if (is_array($input) && next_element($input)) { // case with multidimentional array
            
            check_in($input);
            $check_in_result[] = "There are should be recursion!!!!!";

        } else { // case with one simple array
            $check_in_result[] = $input;
               }
    }
    return $check_in_result;
}
```

Have tried with array_walk_recursive() but that function is working with all elements and returns as result one array with all keys and values. In this case it should be array(array1, array2, array3, array4) for next stage which is foreach loop.

As resutl it should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [House] => Baratheon
            [Sigil] => A crowned stag
            [Motto] => Ours is the Fury
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Leader] => Eddard Stark
            [House] => Stark
            [Motto] => Winter is Coming
            [Sigil] => A grey direwolf
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [SomeArray] => You are cool
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [House] => Lannister
            [Leader] => Tywin Lannister
            [Sigil] => A golden lion
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Q] => Z
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you specify what your desired result is? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: yes, Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [House] => Baratheon
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Leader] => Eddard Stark
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [SomeArray] => You are cool
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [House] => Lannister
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Q] => Z
        )

)

Comment: I delete some part of array it was too big, it should be one array which includes other arrays in one level

Comment: Add new information by editing your question (the `Edit` link can be found at the bottom fo your post). Comments aren't suitable for extensive pieces of information (as you've discovered). You should be able to add the entire output there.

Comment: I can't edit just aswer

Comment: Are you sure you can't [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67196947/edit)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recursive function like this:

```
function parseMyArray($array) {
    $result = [];
    $row = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, parseMyArray($item));
        } else {
            $row[$key] = $item;
        }
    }
    return !empty($row) ? array_merge($result, [$row]) : $result;
}

$result = parseMyArray($arrays);

print_r($result);
```

At each level of a function call, all scalar values with their keys are collected into one array as `$row` and merged with the `$result` of a nested function call.

[fiddle](https://3v4l.org/KKrQA)